# Capybara: page_find doesn't seem to be working with double slash (//)

Tags: capybara

Trying to validate the 2nd link in the following HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="/tv">TV</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="/radio">Radio</a>
  </li>
```

with the following expression:

```
page.find(:xpath, "//div[@id='navigation']//a").should have_content('Radio')
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
expected there to be content "Radio" in "TV"
```

Should'nt the find method research in all the A elements inside the DIV node as I'm using a double slash? Could this be a bug or am I doing something wrong?

And is there any other way to be able to validate the 2nd link?

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case [find](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) will find first `a` in Capybara < 2.0 and will raise an Ambiguous Match exception in Capybara 2.0 as there are more than one elements with such locator.

I suggest you to do the following:

```
page.should have_selector('#navigation a', text: 'Radio')
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey, I thought I had to use page.find in order to navigate to an element.

page.should finds the element I was searching for. Cheers!!

Comment: @mickael Capybara has plenty of [Matchers](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers). research them